# Wonder about syntax and language for two code examples

Tags: java, syntax

I watched a video about composition and inheritance.
In this video I saw two different examples of code syntax that I have not seen before.

Generally the code looks like java but I don't recognize these two code snippets.

Would appriciate if someone would explain what the code does and if the code is java or another language.
Thanks!

---

First code:

```
public void replacePixel(Pixel[,] pixels] {....}
```

Here it is the syntax `[,]` that is new to me.
What does it do?

---

Second code:

```
void saveClicked(){
    file?.load(image);
}
```

Here is is the syntax `?.`
What does it do?

Tried to use a online java compiler and the syntax did not seem to work.

Comment: It is not Java, but C#

Comment: Regardless, I stay away from YouTube tutorials as they are usually lousy.  This one is no exception.  For one thing, the black background makes it hard to read.  I find books better for learning just about anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void replacePixel(Pixel[,] pixels) {....}
```

Im not sure if this is valid for Java, but in C#:

`[,]` here means that as an argument you want to get two-dimensional array. If you want three-dimensional array you can use `[,,]` and so on.

```
void saveClicked(){
    file?.load(image);
}
```

Here `?` is a conditional operator that says: if file is not null then do `file.load(image)`. Otherwise, if file is null do nothing. This can be converted to:

```
void saveClicked(){
    if(file != null){
        file.load(image);
    }
}
```